# Странный постфикс в адресе страницы при загрузке из phpstorm

Tags: html, phpstorm

При открытии любого `html` документа из `phpstorm` добавляется странная приписка в конце адреса.
Примерно такая:

> .../somefile.html**?_ijt=tfkjtn6pki0sh8p3vrtmtb4c1r**

Откуда оно берется и что означает? Раньше не появлялось.

Comment: скорее всего примочка от кеша браузера, в настройках вероятно наклацали.

Answer (score 2):

`_ijt` идет от `IntellijIdea Token`, в исходниках это `TOKEN_PARAM_NAME`:

```
// we must check referrer - if html cached, browser will send request without query
  val token = headers().get(TOKEN_HEADER_NAME)
      ?: QueryStringDecoder(uri()).parameters().get(TOKEN_PARAM_NAME)?.firstOrNull()
      ?: referrer?.let { QueryStringDecoder(it).parameters().get(TOKEN_PARAM_NAME)?.firstOrNull() }
```

[Появилась](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2016/05/11/security-update-for-intellij-based-ides-v2016-1-and-older-versions/) для защиты встроенного сервера от [`CSRF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

P. S. Прошлая неправильная версия:
Рандом добавляется, чтобы браузер не кэшировал контент, иначе какие-то браузеры могут показывать закэшированную версию уже измененного файла, а вы будете слать претензии разработчикам `PHPStorm`.

Это не "приписка", а параметр `URL`.

Comment: Не сходится с кэшем. ибо приходится каждый раз меняя чтото в проекте дважды рефрешить страницу.

Comment: @Next да, ты прав. копнул глубже